# Linux 32 ou 64 bits?

Tags: linux, shell, 64-bits, 32-bits

Como saber se o linux que estou usando é 32 bits ou 64 bits?

Preciso saber qual é a arquitetura do meu kernel e sou novo com linux, gostaria de saber a forma para descobrir isso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tente `uname -m`. O comando vai te dar a seguinte saída:

```
x86_64 ==> 64-bit kernel
i686   ==> 32-bit kernel
```

Com isso você saberá.

Answer (score 4):

Digite no terminal o comando `arch`. Você ira receber um resultado como este `ia64` ou `x86_64` para 64 bits ou `i686` para 32 bits.

Veja mais [aqui](http://elias.praciano.com/2014/07/como-saber-se-sistema-e-32-ou-64-bits-no-linux/).